# Maximum number of mutually high contrast colors

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces

Edit: User @Henry points out that taking the luminance as a first step in calculating the contrast turns this into a one dimensional question, and given the maximum contrast of 21, and the logarithmic scale, the answer turns out to be $3$ colors. It seems that contrast is not the right measure to use here.

Edit 2: I found a great website for picking color schemes for map coloring. https://colorbrewer2.org It is based on the work of Susan Brewer.

Original Post: Suppose you want to display some color-coded visual information, say a map where certain sets of regions need to be displayed in the same color. You would like neighboring regions to be easily distinguishable to the eye, so you want them to have high contrast. So it would be nice to have a pool of easily pairwise distinguishable colors to choose from which is as large as possible. Here is the precise mathematical question, with appropriate definitions:

We take a color to be specified by the values of $r,g,b$ between $0$ and $1$. Now define a normalization function $\varphi\colon \mathbb [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by
$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}x/12.92&\text{if }x<0.3928\\
\left(\frac{x+.055}{1.055}\right)^{2.4} &\text{if } x\geq 0.3928
\end{cases}$$

This lets us define $R=\varphi(r), G=\varphi(g),$ and $ B=\varphi(b)$. Now define relative luminance $$L=0.2126 R+0.7152G+0.0722B.$$

Finally, the contrast between two colors is defined as
$$\text{contrast}=\frac{L_1+0.05}{L_2+0.05}, \text{ where } L_1\geq L_2$$

Contrast above $3.0$ is considered good enough for UI elements while $5.0$ is the threshold for written text on a background. The contrast between pure black and white is $21$.

Let's adopt the weaker threshold of $3$. My question is what the maximum number of colors is such that the pairwise contrast of each is $\geq 3$.

Comment: Since $3^2 < 21 < 3^3$, it is difficult to see this exceeding three in terms of the way you have set up the question (and two if you use $5$ since $5^1 < 21 < 5^2$).  That seems implausible to me

Comment: @henry I would expect it to be three dimensional, given the three input parameters, but the maximum distance in each direction is not uniform.

Comment: @Henry if 3 is the maximum, that would be disappointing, but good to know.

Comment: The problem is that you are giving each colour a one dimensional $L+0.05$ and then using that to separate. In effect your criteria give you no more colours than you would have  using black and white and shades of grey.   The question would be more interesting if your contrast formula took the $R,G,B$ values of each  to make this three dimensional.

Comment: @henry ah, I see what you're saying. It's a bit like defining distance in euclidean space as a difference in norms as opposed to the norm of the difference. If you take the norm first, you lose all the dimension info.

Comment: A webpage I wrote over two decades ago http://www.se16.info/js/htmlcol.htm (playing with javascript and websafe colours) indirectly illustrated some of the contrast issues - some of the codes such as pink on green are horribly difficult to read

Comment: @henry do you have a proposed alternative metric for color distinguishability of, say, regions on a map?

Comment: @ henry I found a webpage devoted to picking good color schemes for maps! https://colorbrewer2.org There is a 12 color qualitative color scheme that should suit my purposes.

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/how-to-maximize-contrast-between-nodes-on-a-graph